# embedded viewbook album. hide vertical scrollbar in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, scrollbar

There seem to be multiple people who had prolbems with getting IE to hide vertical scrollbars.
But none of the answers seem to work for me.

Manly I think because the overflow ellement does nothing since there isn't realy an overflow, IE just creates an overflow...

the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="pics">
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" "frameborder="0" src="http://viewbookalbum"></iframe></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The css:

```
    body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;    

}
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}
#wrapper #pics {
    margin-left: 10%;
    width:80%;
    height:70%;


}
```

So pretty simple yet perfectly liquid album witouth picture distortion. Works like a charmm in other browsers. But IE puts a vertical scrollbar on the right... :/

I'd love to hear your advice.

Regards,

Mich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding scrolling="no" to the iframe removes the scroll bars for me in IE 9.

Comment: Ha what do you know, could it realy be that simple...? thanks for the quick response!